# Hazelcast uses ephemeral port for outbound traffic in spite of configured specific ports

Tags: java, hazelcast

**Background:**

- I am using Hazelcast 3.5.2
- 3 nodes are configured to be the members of a single cluster
- each node has following network configuration:

  ```
  <network>
  <port auto-increment="false">5701</port>
  <outbound-ports>
      <ports>10000-10005</ports>
  </outbound-ports>
  <join>
      <multicast enabled="false" />
      <tcp-ip enabled="true">
          <member-list>
              <member>{assume ip of node 1}</member>
              <member>{assume ip of node 2}</member>
              <member>{assume ip of node 3}</member>
          </member-list>
      </tcp-ip>
  </join>
  ```
- so, each node has 6 ports for outbound communication, which as per my current understanding of hazelcast, is sufficient for 3 nodes. However, i notice similar to following on each node when doing *netstat* on each node (assume {n} as some non-zero number)

  `@node1
  tcp  {n}  0 {ip of node 1}:5701  {ip of node 2}:35576  ESTABLISHED
  tcp  {n}  0 {ip of node 1}:5701  {ip of node 3}:10001  ESTABLISHED
  tcp  0  {n} {ip of node 1}:54941  {ip of node 2}:5701  ESTABLISHED
  tcp  0  {n} {ip of node 1}:10000  {ip of node 3}:5701  ESTABLISHED
  @node2
  tcp  {n}  0 {ip of node 2}:5701  {ip of node 1}:54941  ESTABLISHED
  tcp  {n}  0 {ip of node 2}:5701  {ip of node 3}:10000  ESTABLISHED
  tcp  0  {n} {ip of node 2}:10003  {ip of node 1}:5701  ESTABLISHED
  tcp  0  {n} {ip of node 2}:35576  {ip of node 3}:5701  ESTABLISHED
  @node3
  tcp  {n}  0 {ip of node 3}:5701  {ip of node 1}:10000  ESTABLISHED
  tcp  {n}  0 {ip of node 3}:5701  {ip of node 2}:10003  ESTABLISHED
  tcp  0  {n} {ip of node 3}:10001  {ip of node 1}:5701  ESTABLISHED
  tcp  0  {n} {ip of node 3}:10000  {ip of node 2}:5701  ESTABLISHED`

**Query:**

- inbound communication config. is well respected by all nodes.
- But, two nodes (out of the three) always opens up some ephemeral port for outbound communication (and does not respect the network config set for them.)
- Does anyone know why? and how one can circumvent the problem?

**Note:** I am quite new to hazelcast so please ask for a specific detail in case i have missed to provide.

Comment: Why do you care about outbound port numbers? Don't constraint them at all, and eliminate any futile firewall rules that affect them as well.

Comment: i agree with you @EJP. But unfortunately, the company for whom we are developing the solution for, do have such firewall restrictions, and hence they do need to know the outbound ports that the app will use.

Comment: can you please open a new issue at github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

can you please share the result of `lsof -a -i -n -P -p ${HAZELCAST_PID}` and `ifconfig` on each of the nodes?

As far as I can tell (see [SocketConnector](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.5.2/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/nio/tcp/SocketConnector.java#L182)), when property `hazelcast.socket.client.bind` is `true` (which is the default value), Hazelcast will attempt to bind to the specific ports provided in the `<outbound-ports>` element for a number of retries, then fail with an exception which is not consistent with the out-of-range client port you see open.